# Javascript won't run when visiting page second time

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got an index.php with a listview containing links to profile.php which takes an id paramter with a specific ID:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="choice_list">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
            <li><a href="profile.php?id=1" data-transition="slidedown"><img src="martin.jpg"/>Martin</a></li>
            <li><a href="profile.php?id=2" data-transition="slidedown"><img src="liisa.jpg"/>Liisa</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In profile.php I include my profile.js file which must run a bunch of stuff within:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Loads specific user data via API calls

});
```

PROBLEM: When I visit profile.php the first time it all works fine, but when visiting it again my Javascript (profile.js) won't run. I know similar questions have been asked before and I've checked a bunch of them out, but I didn't really understand the answers, and the couple of solutions I tried didn't work out at all (trying to stop jqm from page caching and whatnot). Is there a somewhat simple solution to this problem that could be applied to my code?

Using jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js

Thanks in advance

/Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jQuery mobile documentation for events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html) states this:

> **Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()**
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.

I think `pageinit` is only fired the first time a page is loaded, so if you go to a page, then go to another page, then go back to the first page, the init event will not fire the second time. To overcome this, you can use the `pageshow` event maybe as well

Comment: Thanks, it did solve the problem with the javascript not running. Now I got a bunch of new problem instead though, but that's another story. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :) What kind of new problems..?